# If the support of an extender is a limit ordinal, then it is a cardinal

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

The following fact is mentioned in the "An Outline of Inner Model Theory" article in the handbook, and I was wondering if I am proving it correctly.

Now this is the setup: assume that $\vec{E}$ is a fine extender sequence and $\alpha \in \mbox{dom}(\vec{E})$, with $E_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ and let $\nu = \nu(E_\alpha)$ and let $i:J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha \rightarrow \mbox{Ult}(J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha, E_\alpha)$ be the canonical embedding and $\kappa = \mbox{crit}(i)$. We know that $J^{i(\vec{E}\upharpoonright\alpha)}_\alpha = J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha$ and that $i(\vec{E}\upharpoonright\alpha)$ is acceptable at all $\beta < \sup_{\gamma<\alpha}i(\gamma)$. Now I want to show that if $\nu$ is a limit ordinal, then it is a cardinal of both $J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha$ and $\mbox{Ult}(J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha, E_\alpha)$. By acceptability and the fact that $\alpha = \nu^+$, we can reduce this to showing that $\nu$ is a cardinal of $J^{i(\vec{E}\upharpoonright\alpha)}_\alpha = J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha$.

So suppose not, and let $\theta < \nu$ be such that $\exists h \in J^{i(\vec{E}\upharpoonright\alpha)}_\alpha$ such that $h:\theta\rightarrow\nu$ is onto. And since these live in the ultrapower, let $a, b, f, g$ be such that $\theta = [a, f]_{E_\alpha}$ and $\nu = [b, g]_{E_\alpha}$, such that $\max(a\cup b) < \nu$; and this is possible, since $\nu$ is the supremum of the generators. Now since $\nu$ is a limit, either $\nu = \kappa^+$ and we are done, or there exists $\xi <\nu$ a generator of $E_\alpha$, such that not only $\theta < \xi$, but also $\max(a\cup b) < \xi$. Now notice that
$$\mbox{Ult}(J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha, E_\alpha) \models ``[a, f]_{E_\alpha} \mbox{ surjects onto } [b, g]_{E_\alpha}",$$
but now since $\max(a\cup b) < \xi$, by the factor lemma we have that:
$$\mbox{Ult}(J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha, E_\alpha\upharpoonright\xi) \models ``[a, f]_{E_\alpha\upharpoonright\xi} \mbox{ surjects onto } [b, g]_{E_\alpha\upharpoonright\xi}",$$
and again by the factor lemma and the fact that $\xi$ is the critical point of the factor map, we can observe that $\theta = [a, f]_{E_\alpha\upharpoonright\xi}$ and that $[b, g]_{E_\alpha\upharpoonright\xi} \ge \xi$. But then $\theta$ surjects onto $\xi$ inside $\mbox{Ult}(J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha, E_\alpha\upharpoonright\xi)$, which is a contradiction, since $\xi$ is the critical point of the factor map and so is a cardinal inside $\mbox{Ult}(J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha, E_\alpha\upharpoonright\xi)$. And this proves the claim.

Is my above proof correct? I am asking this, because another idea I had in mind, failed(I was trying to show that each generator is a cardinal and that $\nu$ is a limit of cardinals and so is a cardinal, which fails as mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247358/are-generators-of-extenders-cardinals).) and I was hoping to know if this other approach works.

Comment: Note that you used the variable $f$ in two distinct ways, which might be confusing for the reader.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll edit it right now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s correct. (I’ve never thought about it exactly this way. There’s also a slightly different argument which starts similarly but in which you don’t have to consider the factor ultrapower...But it comes down to similar principles.) Regarding your parenthetical remark in the last paragraph, actually every cardinal $\lambda$ of the model $M=\mathcal{J}^{\mathbb{E}}_\alpha$ such that $(\kappa^+)^M<\lambda<\alpha$ is a limit of generators. But there can also be limits of generators $\lambda$ in that interval which are not cardinals of $M$.

Comment: Thanks for verifying this. Also, I would really appreciate it if you could give a reference or proof for the last statement you mentioned. I tried to prove it myself but couldn't, and I think if I see proofs for statements like this, it may help me build a better understanding of this stuff.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri No problem. Do you mean the part "there can also be limits of generators $\lambda$ in that interval which are not cardinals of $M$"? In any case, the key to both things (cardinals $\lambda$ being limits of generators, and also getting other limits of generators) is the initial segment condition; did you think about that? (There are counterexamples without it.)

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant the "cardinals are limits of generators" bit. I did think about that, in the sense that first let $\eta = \nu(E_\alpha|\lambda)$ and I tried to show that $\eta = \lambda$ by noting that if $E_\alpha|\eta$ is not of type $Z$, then it in some form can be computed inside the big ultrapower($\mbox{Ult}(J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha, E_\alpha)$); using the initial segment condition.

Comment: And so we can compute the set $A = \{\xi<\lambda:\xi \mbox{ is a generator for } E_\alpha|\eta\}$ inside there, and now if $\nu(E_\alpha|\lambda)$ is a limit ordinal, then by the factor lemma the critical point of $\sigma_\lambda$(the factor map for $E_\alpha|\lambda$) should be equal to the supremum of $A$. But $A\subset \lambda$ and $\mbox{crit}(\sigma_\lambda) \ge \lambda$, so $\lambda = \eta$. But I still don't know how to prove this in the case where $E_\alpha|\eta$ is not type $Z$ and $\eta$ is a successor and the case that $E_\alpha|\eta$ *is* type $Z$.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Hmm, $\mathrm{crit}(\sigma_\lambda)\geq\sup(A)$ but why should it be equal? Anyway, you can argue as follows (to see that $\eta=\lambda$): Use $E_\alpha|\lambda$ to compute a surjection $\eta\to\lambda$ which is in the model; the fact that it's in the model uses the initial segment condition.

Comment: Well, intuitively I was assuming that $\mbox{Ult}(J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha, E_\alpha|\lambda)$ is the direct limit of the system $\langle \mbox{Ult}(J^{\vec{E}}_\alpha, E_\alpha|\xi), \sigma_{\xi\bar{\xi}}\rangle_{\xi<\bar{\xi}\mbox{ are generators } <\lambda}$, where $\sigma_{\xi,\bar{\xi}}$ are the relevant factor maps, and since everything commutes, we have $\sigma_\lambda \circ \sigma_{\xi\lambda} = \sigma_\xi$ for every generator and in the case that $\eta$ is a limit, then $\mbox{crit}(\sigma_\lambda) = \sup_{\xi<\bar{\xi}\mbox{ generators } <\lambda}\{\mbox{crit}(\sigma_{\xi\bar{\xi}})\}$.

Comment: And since we assume $\eta$ is limit, $\sup_{\xi<\bar{\xi} \mbox{generators} <\lambda}\{\mbox{crit}(\sigma_{\xi\bar{\xi}})\} = \sup A$, since $\sigma_{\xi\bar{\xi}}(\xi) = \bar{\xi}$. Is this not correct?

Comment: Oh, I just realized that we only get $\mbox{crit}(\sigma_\lambda) \ge \sup_{\xi<\bar{\xi}\mbox{ generators } <\lambda}\{\mbox{crit}(\sigma_{\xi\bar{\xi}})\}$ and what you say is correct, so I don't even have a proof for the case where $\eta$ is a limit. Is there some straightforward way to prove this, then? Since this discussion is getting long, I think it's best if I ask this as another question and maybe if you have the time, you can answer it there?

Comment: Right, we just get $\geq$. (Also, I don't see that equality $\sigma_{\xi\bar{\xi}}(\xi)=\bar{\xi}$.) To show that $\eta=\lambda$: First consider the case that $E_\alpha|\lambda$ is non-type Z. Then $E_\alpha|\eta$ is in the model. But from $E_\alpha|\eta$ we can compute $E_\alpha|\lambda$, so $E_\alpha|\lambda$ is in, and also the same computation gives a surjection $\eta^{<\omega}\to\lambda$ in the model, which is enough. (We have here $\eta\geq(\kappa^+)^M$ by definition of natural length $\nu(E_\alpha|\lambda)$; use the representation of elements in the ultrapower to get a surjection.)

Comment: Oh, right. To make sure I understand it, we can represent any $\beta<\lambda$ as some $[a, f]$ where $a \subset \eta$ and $f:[\kappa]^{|a|} \rightarrow \kappa$ and by acceptability and $\eta \ge (\kappa^+)^M$ we have the surjection, right? And what happens when $E_\alpha|\eta$ is type $Z$? I don't think we can do the same there.

Comment: I guess it should move to chat...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123824/discussion-between-farmer-s-and-shervin-sorouri).